# Hiding Select2 options

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-select2

I'm trying to hide some of the Select2 options, but when I do something like this:

```html
<option style="display: none;">...</option>
```

Select2 ignores it, unlike when I disable an option, or make it "readonly".

Any ideas?

Comment: I solve the same problem , you could see this topic , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064487/select2-hide-certain-options-dynamically/25085053#25085053

Answer (score 5):

I resolved this problem with an epic solution.

My version of select2 is 4.0.5 and only requires using the `hidden` property (you can change its logic) in each hidden options, without requiring `style="display:none"` (more clean for me).

```
<select class="select2">
   <option value="">Select</option>
   <option value="1">One</option>
   <option value="2" hidden>Two</option>
   <option value="3">One</option>
</select>
```

Right now, the only code needed is in the initialization of select2:

```
$('.select2').select2({
   templateResult: function(option) {
      if(option.element && (option.element).hasAttribute('hidden')){
         return null;
      }
      return option.text;
   }
});
```

`hidden` is a standard property and you can dynamicaly change it with `attr` and `removeAttr` jQuery methods: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_hidden.asp

Comment: I don't see it working in my case. Can you take a look? https://jsfiddle.net/vh2L1oct/4/

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this subject when looking for an answer to the same problem and i resolved it using the 'templateResult' callback of select2.

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="1" data-show="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option> <!-- option i want to hide -->
</select>
```

At the initialization of my select2 :

```
var dataIWantToShow = '1';
$('#mySelect').select2({
    templateResult: function(option) {
        var myOption = $('#mySelect').find('option[value="' + option.id + '"');
        if (myOption.data('show') == dataIWantToshow) {
            return option.text;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

To avoid having empty li displayed in the select2 list of options i added the following css :

```
li.select2-results__option:empty {
    display: none;
}
```

This solution does not add or remove options from the original select.

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/2308/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the question is old but I have got here for the same problem.
I am using the select2 v. 3.5.1, I was able to fix it like this:

I add a class on the option that I want to hide:

```
<option class="hide_me">...</option>
```

that is supposed to be something like:

```
.hide_me {
  display: none!important;
}
```

Basically I do the same you was doing by the style attribute but using a css class. The style attribute doesn't work for me too (even when the multi select2 seems to hide the selected options that way).

Hope this can help.

Comment: IDK about select2 v3.5.1, but this solution just doesn't work in v4.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the options which should not be available. If you need to do it dynamically in JavaScript, you can clone the fully populated `<select>` element at first. At any given time you can remove all options from the original `<select>` and copy back only those options which you'd like to be available at the moment. That way you don't loose any styling, meta-data, sorting etc.

Here is an example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var select = $(".yourselect");
    var selectClone = select.clone();

    function updateSelect() {
        var oldVal = select.val();

        // first, remove all options
        select.find("option").remove();

        // now add only those options that should be available from the clone
        // replace "data-show='yes'" with whatever you criteria might be
        var options = selectClone.find("option[data-show='yes']").clone();
        select.append(options);

        // restore previously selected value if it is still possible
        if (select.find("option[value='" + oldVal + "']").length === 0) {
            oldVal = "";
        }
        select.val(oldVal);

        // update select2
        select.trigger('change');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the option and then add some css to hide the options:

`<option disabled="disabled">text</option>`

CSS:

```
.select2-container--bootstrap .select2-results__option[aria-disabled=true] { 
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

Add this style in your page

```
<style>
    li[aria-disabled='true'] {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

add a attribute in option in Select2 dropdown

```
<select class='select2'>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option data-status="0" value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

add this Jquery Code for select2

```
$(".select2").select2();
$(".select2 option[data-status='0']").prop("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score -1):

why you need that?
Simple: remove this option!

If you need to show only in some cases you can use javascript.

using jQuery example:

```
if (condition) {
    $('#yourselect').append('<option value="foo" selected="selected">Foo</option>');
}
```

Comment: I already did that, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: I'm tired of answers that just tell you not to do something. What if he wants to preserve the sort order an option he plans to show again?

Answer (score -5):

You can disable it with `disabled="disabled"` attribute.

```
<option value="4" disabled="disabled">Product 4</option>
```

Refer this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/vhKdw/)

Comment: This doesn't hide the option... And your example was simple html, I'm talking about the select2 plugin.

Comment: Add some css and it will `.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-disabled=true] { display: none;}`