# How to hide (NOT remove) option in select2?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

Is it possible to hide the option from select2 without removing it?

My current code only disables the option:

```
$('#company_id').change(function () {
    var company_name =  $("#company_id option:selected").text();
    var $owner_id = $("#owner_id");

    $owner_id.select2("destroy"); 

    $("#owner_id option:not(:contains('(" + company_name + ")'))")  
        .prop('disabled',true);

    $("#owner_id option:contains('(" + company_name + ")')")
        .prop('disabled',false);

    $owner_id.select2();
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064487/select2-hide-certain-options-dynamically

Answer (score 1):

You can comment HTML code with jQuery, your code will look something like this:

```
$('#company_id').change(function () {
    var company_name =  $("#company_id option:selected").text();
    var $owner_id = $("#owner_id");

    $owner_id.select2("destroy"); 

    //Comment element
    element = $("#owner_id option:not(:contains('(" + company_name + ")'))");
    comment = document.createComment(element.get(0).outerHTML);
    element.replaceWith(comment);

    //Unomment element
    $("#owner_id option:contains('(" + company_name + ")')").replaceWith(comment.nodeValue);

    $owner_id.select2();
});
```

If not works try to do it inside a loop for each element to comment or uncomment, I will try it later.

Answer (score -1):

use css instead prop

```
.css('display', 'none');
```

and

```
.css('display', 'block');
```