# jQuery Select2 - How to hide Select2 Optgroup

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a 'Select2' select where I'm trying to hide select optgroups along with their options, however this is not happening.

The CCS for hiding the options and the optgroups are as follows:

```
.select2-results .select2-disabled,
    .select2-results__option[aria-disabled=true] {
        display: none;
    }
.select2-results .select2-disabled,
    .select2-results__group[aria-disabled=true] {
        display: none;
    }
```

However, while the options are being hidden, as desired, the 'OptGroups' are not being hidden the same way. 
The JQuery used here is:

```
jQuery('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
        var CityOption = jQuery('#City').find('option[value=Delhi], option[value=Bangalore]');
        var CityOptionGroup = jQuery('#City').find('optgroup[value=North], optgroup[value=South]');
        jQuery(CityOption).prop('disabled', 'true');
        jQuery(CityOptionGroup).prop('disabled', 'true');
    });
```

I have also seen this query being raised in this question [Select2: Hide certain optgroup dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48078990/select2-hide-certain-optgroup-dynamically) where one has suggested adding the options using a data array source, but this also does not allow you to hide the OptGroup dynamically through jQuery, as I require it.

Find the complete code below:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery('#City').select2({
    width: '100%'
  });

  jQuery('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
    var CityOption = jQuery('#City').find('option[value=Delhi], option[value=Bangalore], option[value=Chennai]');
    var CityOptionGroup = jQuery('#City').find('optgroup[value=North], optgroup[value=South]');
    console.log(CityOption, CityOptionGroup);
    jQuery(CityOption).prop('disabled', 'true');
    jQuery(CityOptionGroup).prop('disabled', 'true');
  });
});
```

```css
.select2-results .select2-disabled,
.select2-results__option[aria-disabled=true] {
  display: none;
}

.select2-results .select2-disabled,
.select2-results__group[aria-disabled=true] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/js/select2.min.js"></script>

Select City
<select id="City">
  <option></option>
  <optgroup value=West label="West">
    <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup value=North label="North">
    <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup value=South label="South">
    <option value="Bangalore">Bangalore</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

<input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Click to hide North & South" />
```

Answer (score 1):

For others who happen to have been struggling with this issue, after a lot of digging, I just found out that this issue has been taken care of in the latest version 4.0.8 : https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3347

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks!!