# Select2 conditionally adding a custom class to list item elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I need to be able to add a custom class on the `change` event on a select 2 multiselect to certain `li` elements, based on certain conditions.

I can add this class to the `li` using the following code, however this does not work when added into the `change` event.  I will appreciate any help thanks.

The dropdown list item still needs to remain clickable and the user should still have the ability to select/non select it, however in the multiselect box it should not appear.

```
 ($('#SelectId').data('select2').$selection)[0].children[0].children[0].classList.add("TestClass");
```

Comment: Hooking into the `change` event for an `<li>` element will not work, because only `<input>`, `<select>` and `<textarea>` *have* a change event. `<li>` does not.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Thanks for helping, is there any way I can hide certain `li` in the `change` event without giving them a class?

Comment: `<li>` does not *have* a change event. Are you asking how you can change the display of `<li>` elements when a *different* element is changed?

Comment: @ObsidianAge Yes, for example if I select test, test2, and test3 from the dropdown, they now appear in the multiselect box, can I give test2 and test3 a class, or do something to hide them in the multiselect but not the dropdown, only on the change of say test3?

Comment: give a look to [Select2: Hide certain options dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064487/select2-hide-certain-options-dynamically)

Comment: @gaetanoM Thanks, just took a look, however using the JS Bin on this answer, it appears the disabled option is then not clickable in the drop-down list, which will not work.