# Hide options in select2 multi select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I need to hide/show options from **select2 multi-select**

I have tried something like this but option Two is not hidden:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test').select2();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
 <select id="test" multiple style="width:250px">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2" style='display:none;'>Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
```

I have added a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/sindhujagovindaraju/xpvt214o/738000/

Comment: Have you tried `visibility:hidden`?

Comment: @Luca Yes. but no result.

Comment: This seems to be working fine can you check versions

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064487/select2-hide-certain-options-dynamically

Comment: @RupeshAgarwal: I have added a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sindhujagovindaraju/xpvt214o/738000/

Comment: @Gauravjoshi This is not same as the question you have commented. This is a different issue I am facing.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use "disabled" instead of "display: none" and write css like below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").select2();
});
```

```css
.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-disabled=true] { display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
 <select id="test" multiple style="width:250px">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2" disabled>Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code:

option[value=2] {display: none;}

best if you add for each li element a css class/id dynamically and target them instead of value which might dynamic

ps: IE might be problematic a bit though [Options with display:none not hidden in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373558/options-with-displaynone-not-hidden-in-ie)

Comment: It does not work for any browser. check the code i have updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .Select-input option:nth-child(4){display: none;}
```

Comment: yeah. no results :(

Comment: In you case just try with ".Select-input option:nth-child(2){display: none;}"

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.