# jQuery function to hide second select dropdown options on page load but display based on the first select option value with if condition

Tags: html, jquery, select, dropdown, jquery-select2

**Description:**

I'm trying to create a jQuery function where the options in the second select dropdown are initially hidden on page load, but should be displayed based on the selected value in the first select dropdown using if conditions. I have the following example code, but it's not working perfectly:

```
<select id="firstSelect">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>

<!-- Second select dropdown -->
<select id="secondSelect">
    <option value="A">Choice A</option>
    <option value="B">Choice B</option>
    <option value="C">Choice C</option>
    <option value="D">Choice D</option>
</select>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Initialize Select2 on both select dropdowns
        $('#firstSelect, #secondSelect').select2();

        // Hide options on page load
        $('#secondSelect option').hide();

        // Event listener for change event on first select dropdown
        $('#firstSelect').on('change', function() {
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();

            // Reset the second select dropdown
            $('#secondSelect').val(null).trigger('change.select2');

            // Hide/show options in the second select dropdown based on the selected value
            if (selectedValue === '1') {
                $('#secondSelect option[value="A"]').show();
                $('#secondSelect option[value="B"]').hide();
                $('#secondSelect option[value="C"]').hide();
                $('#secondSelect option[value="D"]').hide();
            } else if (selectedValue === '2') {
                $('#secondSelect option[value="A"]').hide();
                $('#secondSelect option[value="B"]').show();
                $('#secondSelect option[value="C"]').hide();
                $('#secondSelect option[value="D"]').hide();
            } else if (selectedValue === '3') {
                $('#secondSelect option[value="A"]').hide();
                $('#secondSelect option[value="B"]').hide();
                $('#secondSelect option[value="C"]').show();
                $('#secondSelect option[value="D"]').hide();
            } else if (selectedValue === '4') {
                $('#secondSelect option[value="A"]').hide();
                $('#secondSelect option[value="B"]').hide();
                $('#secondSelect option[value="C"]').hide();
                $('#secondSelect option[value="D"]').show();
            } else {
                $('#secondSelect option').hide();
            }
        });

        // Trigger change event on first select dropdown on page load
        $('#firstSelect').trigger('change');
    });

</script>
```

The above code is supposed to hide the options in the secondSelect dropdown on page load and display specific options based on the selected value in the firstSelect dropdown. However, it's not working as expected. The options are not being hidden or displayed correctly based on the selected value.

I have already tried using the show() and hide() methods, as well as resetting the second select dropdown with val(null).trigger('change.select2'), but it doesn't seem to work properly.

I would appreciate any help or guidance on how to modify this code to achieve the desired functionality.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Not sure if select2 actually cares about whether options are hidden using `display: none` (which is what `.hide()` will do) - you might have to actually _remove_ them from the underlaying select element. And triggering the change event only makes sense _after_ you manipulated the options, not before ...

Comment: @CBroe can you create the example code?

Comment: **Confirmed** select2 ignores the `display` css of `<option>`.   https://jsfiddle.net/dfpeu3cw/   this is when the select2 is built on a select with hidden options - hiding an option after the select2 has been built is even *less* likely to work.

Comment: `.val(null).trigger('change.select2')` is used to *update* the selected *value* in select2, it won't *rebuild* the select2 based on underlying changes to the source `select` (even if it did consider hidden options)

Comment: This question/answers provides a solution using select2 option templates and adding a class to the underyling select>option, though doesn't include a working example, so I'm not 100% it will work when changing the select>option without additional code/changes:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064487/select2-hide-certain-options-dynamically