# select2: reduce number of options with a second select menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, wcvendors

We have a clothing product upload form, and the clothing item's size can be in a number of different international formats: UK, French, US, International, and so on.

That means that the select2 menu for Size is very lengthy.  We'd like to have another select menu before this Size one, with the format in it (choose one of UK, French, US etc) and that filters the options in the select2 menu to just those ones from the chosen nationality.

So if a user selects 'France' in the first select, then FR-32, FR-34, FR-36 etc are left available in the select2.  If they choose 'UK', then UK-8, UK-10, UK-12 and so on are left.

I found this SO: [Hiding Select2 options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143049/hiding-select2-options)  but I cant get my head round the jquery for identifying the option tags in the select2 to add the hidden attribute to (if that's the right way to go about it).

Any help gratefully received!

EDIT (added the relevant bits I've tried):

First select, to choose nationality:

```
<select class="size-nationality">
    <option selected value="">Please choose:</option>
    <option value="UK">UK</option>
    <option value="FR">French</option>
    <option value="IT">Italian</option>
    <option value="US">US</option>
    <option value="Int">International</option>
</select>
```

Main select2 with the options:

```
<select class="select2 select_prod_size select2-hidden-accessible"
id="wcv_custom_taxonomy_product_size[]" 
name="wcv_custom_taxonomy_product_size[]" 
aria-hidden="true">
    <option value="">Select Size</option>   
    <option class="level-0" value="258">UK 06</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="252">UK 08</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="253">UK 10</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="254">UK 12</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="255">UK 14</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="256">UK 16</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="257">UK 18</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="264">FR 32</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="265">FR 34</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="266">FR 36</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="267">FR 38</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="267">FR 40</option>
</select>
```

jquery to comment out the options that are not required (just comments all of them):

```
$(function() {
    $('.size-nationality').on('change', function() {
      var val = this.value;
      // var val = this.html;
        element = $("select.select_prod_size option:not(:contains('("+val+")'))");
        comment = document.createComment(element.get(0).outerHTML);
        element.replaceWith(comment);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Hi, can you show your html and jquery code which you have tried ?

Comment: @Swati - ok, i've updated, cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use matcher method of *select2* plugin . So ,whenever user select any value from 1st select-box you can filter options inside 2nd select-box using `data.text.indexOf(val) != -1` .

***Demo code*** :

```js
$(function() {
  $("select").select2({
    "width": "150px"
  });
  $('.size-nationality').on('change', function() {
    var val = this.value;
    $("select[id='wcv_custom_taxonomy_product_size[]']").val("").trigger("select2"); //remove any selected value
    $("select[id='wcv_custom_taxonomy_product_size[]']").select2({
      matcher: function(term, data, option) {
        //here data is json obj then,,use .text to get option text 
        if (data.text.indexOf(val) != -1) {
          return data; //return...data if found..
        } else {
          return null; //return null..if not found
        }

      }
    })

  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://woocommerce.github.io/selectWoo/accessibility-testing/select2.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://woocommerce.github.io/selectWoo/accessibility-testing/selectWoo.full.js"></script>


<select class="size-nationality">
  <option selected value="">Please choose:</option>
  <option value="UK">UK</option>
  <option value="FR">French</option>
  <option value="IT">Italian</option>
  <option value="US">US</option>
  <option value="Int">International</option>
</select>
<select class="select2 select_prod_size" id="wcv_custom_taxonomy_product_size[]" name="wcv_custom_taxonomy_product_size[]" aria-hidden="true">
  <option value="">Select Size</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="258">UK 06</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="252">UK 08</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="253">UK 10</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="254">UK 12</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="255">UK 14</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="256">UK 16</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="257">UK 18</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="264">FR 32</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="265">FR 34</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="266">FR 36</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="267">FR 38</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="267">FR 40</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is great, thanks Swati.  However, after selecting 'UK' from the first select, I try to open the select2 with the options and it gives an error in the console:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined".
It relates to the 'matcher:' line in the jquery.  There are multiple select2 elements on the page, fwiw.

Comment: Are you seeing that behaviour in above snippet ? Also , from second selectbox i have removed `select2-hidden-accessible` class it was hiding select box.

Comment: I'm seeing that error in my site, when trying the code you kindly provided. 
I just took a closer look at the version of select2.  It's actually 'selectwoo':
 * SelectWoo 1.0.9
 * https://github.com/woocommerce/selectWoo

Comment: Hi , sorry for late reply .Please see updated code .

Comment: Thanks swati - I tried the updated code, and it now appears to make all of the options the same as the first one (UK 6) and also comment them out.  Not sure what's happening in there.

Comment: are you seeing that behaviour in above code as well ?

Comment: No, it works well in the snippet above.  I see the problems above when i try it in the page in my site.

Comment: All of the options become:   <!--<option value="">Select Size</option>-->   (which is a commented-out version of the first option that is there when the page loads)

Comment: So, what does `console.log(data.text)` gives you ? Can you print that and see

Comment: hi swati - i had more of a play on this and it was something else on the page interfering.  I've tried it on a cleaner version of the page and it works perfectly!  Thanks so much for your help and patience